# Android ACTION_SCREEN_OFF intent meaning

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

In Google documentation about [ACTION_SCREEN_OFF](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) they write:

> This broadcast is sent when the device becomes non-interactive which may have nothing to do with the screen turning off. To determine the actual state of the screen, use Display.getState().

So I asking when the screen becomes non-interactive and it still turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press the power button to lock the screen (or even if the device's screen lights get off, due to inactivity), at that time it goes to a non-interactive state.

And yes, the device will be turned on.